# Конструкторы в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Если в Kotlin есть несколько вторичных конструкторов внутри класса, как компилятор узнает какой я вызываю?

Comment: по передаваемым аргументам. Уточните свой вопрос, что за класс

Comment: А как вы сами решаете, какой вызвать?

Answer (score 1):

Согласен. Вам следовало бы привести ваш класс. Если у класса N конструкторов, то они все должны отличаться параметрами. Нельзя создать два конструктора с одинаковыми типами и кол-вом параметров. При компиляции в байткод методы (и конструкторы) преобразуются в методы с новыми названиями: название методы + тип переменной №1 + тип переменной № 2+ ... + тип возвращаемой переменной. (я несолько упростил, но принцип именно такой). Поэтому, нельзя создать два конструктора или метода с одинаковыми типами и вол-вом переменных (даже если название переменных будет отличаться, компилятор будет смотреть именно на тип)